# Un-specializing C++ template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

Basically what I want to do is as follows. Let's assume we have a template member function **foo**:

```
template <typename T>
T SomeClass::foo();
```

and somehow a user passed **map< string, int >** as a template argument:

```
foo<map<string, int>>();
```

What I want to do here is, when defining the function **foo**, to get the inner types, **string** and **int**. I tried much guesswork to un-specialize the argument but was of no avail.

```
template <map<typename K, typename V>>
map<K, V> SomeClass::foo();  // absolutely illegal
```

I thought about using partial specialization, but it didn't work as **foo** is a class member function.

Comment: your "absolutely illegal" is on the wrong line. You can do `template <typename K,typename V> map<K,V> SomeClass:foo();`

Comment: `T::key_type`/`T::mapped_type` ?

Comment: Do you expect `T` be any type, or only `std::map`. If you don't have specialization, what do you expect from `foo<int>` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes I expect T as any type, although I'm going to consider a limited set of containers like map, vector..

Answer (score 1):

If you want a generic way of grabbing inner types from a template, you can use explicit specialization:

```
template <typename T>
struct unpack;

template <template <typename...> class C, typename A, typename B>
struct unpack<C<A, B>>
{
    using first  = A;
    using second = B;
};
```

Usage:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<string,
    typename unpack<map<string, int>>::first
>);

static_assert(std::is_same_v<int,
    typename unpack<map<string, int>>::second
>);
```

---

If you only care about doing that when calling a function, you can just make the function a template:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
void foo(std::map<K, V>);
```

Comment: And to avoid overloading functions, the `unpack` should probably return some default implementations for types that are not instantiations of binary templates, or at least signal of it via bool member flags.

Comment: Actually all the hassles come from what I tried to return a template argument type. I would be much easier if I simply return values through the reference argument. But still I'm curious about whether the un-specialization thing is even possible in C++ only using the basic template syntax.

Comment: @GwangmuLee Sure it's quite, it's just you'll need to define a getter, as Vittorio's `unpack` ... and you'll not be able to cover _all_ the possible options.

Comment: So you mean we need to manually write an unpacker.. It's somewhat disappointing.

Answer (score 1):

Off the cuff:

```
template< class T >
struct Foo
{
    static auto impl() -> T;
};

template< class K, class V >
struct Foo< map< K, V > >
{
    static auto impl() -> map< K, V >;
};

template< class T >
auto foo()
    -> T
{ return Foo<T>::impl(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possible solution.  The method foo dispatches to a foo_detail method that take a pointer to T as a parameter.  That parameter is not used in foo_detail.  Instead, the parameter allows the overload resolution to select which foo_detail is called.

The solution has a clunky feel because of the unused parameter.  Fortunately, this can be hidden in the private portion of SomeClass so that users of SomeClass don't have to know about it.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
using std::map;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

class SomeClass
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    T foo()
        {
            return foo_detail((T *)0);
        }

private:    
    template<typename T>
    T foo_detail(T *)
        {
            cout << "foo called with type " << typeid(T).name() << endl;
            return T();
        }

    template <typename K, typename V>
    map<K, V> foo_detail(map<K, V> *)
        {
            cout << "foo map specialization called with types "
                 << typeid(K).name() << ' ' << typeid(V).name() << endl;
            return map<K,V>();
        }
};

int main()
{
    SomeClass s;
    s.foo<double>();
    s.foo<map<int, string> >();
    return 0;
}
```